# How capture everything before operator in Pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

Referring to [Pyparsing problem with operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059482/pyparsing-problem-with-operators)

I am trying to create pyparsing grammar. I want to capture space separated entity as single word before operator "and"/"or".

Expected result is :

```
(United kingdom or Sweden)
['United kingdom','or','Sweden']
```

What i am getting is

```
['United', 'kingdom','or','Sweden']
```

Code so far

```
from pyparsing import *
import json

QUOTED = quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
OAND = CaselessLiteral("and")
OOR = CaselessLiteral("or")
ONOT = CaselessLiteral("not")
WORDWITHSPACE = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(printables.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")) | White(
    ' ') + ~(White() | OAND | ONOT | OOR)))
TERM = (QUOTED | WORDWITHSPACE)
EXPRESSION = operatorPrecedence(TERM,
                                [
                                    (ONOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
                                    (OAND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                    (OOR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT)
                                ])

STRING = OneOrMore(EXPRESSION) + StringEnd()
```

Comment: What parsing rules do you use?

Comment: Please post the pyparsing expression you are using to get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redefinend WORDWITHSPACE as follows:

```
# space-separated words are easiest to define using just OneOrMore
# must use a negative lookahead for and/not/or operators, and this must come
# at the beginning of the expression
WORDWITHSPACE = OneOrMore(~(OAND | ONOT | OOR) + Word(printables, excludeChars="()"))

# use a parse action to recombine words into a single string
WORDWITHSPACE.addParseAction(' '.join)
```

With these changes to your code sample, I was able to write:

```
tests = """
    # basic test
    United Kingdom or Sweden

    # multiple operators at the same precedence level
    United Kingdom or Sweden or France

    # implicit grouping by precedence - 'and' is higher prec than 'or
    United Kingdom or Sweden and People's Republic of China

    # use ()'s to override precedence of 'and' over 'or
    (United Kingdom or Sweden) and People's Republic of China
    """

EXPRESSION.runTests(tests, fullDump=False)
```

and get

```
# basic test
United Kingdom or Sweden
[['United Kingdom', 'or', 'Sweden']]

# multiple operators at the same precedence level
United Kingdom or Sweden or France
[['United Kingdom', 'or', 'Sweden', 'or', 'France']]

# implicit grouping by precedence - 'and' is higher prec than 'or
United Kingdom or Sweden and People's Republic of China
[['United Kingdom', 'or', ['Sweden', 'and', "People's Republic of China"]]]

# use ()'s to override precedence of 'and' over 'or
(United Kingdom or Sweden) and People's Republic of China
[[['United Kingdom', 'or', 'Sweden'], 'and', "People's Republic of China"]]
```